# Variables in TestClass when developing in python using VisualStudio

Tags: python, visual-studio, unit-testing, tdd

I am learning to develop in python using visual studio. I am implementing a test class. The thing that I got stuck on is where should a variable that will be used across multiple tests be declared. For example in the following code where should calc be declared.

```
 class Test_test1(unittest.TestCase): 

    def test_add_method(self):
        calc = Calculator()
        #more code

    def test_subtract(self):
        calc = Calculator()
        #more code
```

Answer (score 0):

In the scope of the class level and not in the scope of the function.

In the following python example, you can see how to define both:

```
def scope_test():
def do_local():
    spam = "local spam"

def do_nonlocal():
    nonlocal spam
    spam = "nonlocal spam"

def do_global():
    global spam
    spam = "global spam"

spam = "test spam"
do_local()
print("After local assignment:", spam)
do_nonlocal()
print("After nonlocal assignment:", spam)
do_global()
print("After global assignment:", spam)
scope_test()
print("In global scope:", spam)
```

the output is:

```
After local assignment: test spam
After nonlocal assignment: nonlocal spam
After global assignment: nonlocal spam
In global scope: global spam
```